# Using object with group_concat in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, object, group-concat

I'm sure the answer to this question is an easy one (I hope).

I am loading a row from mysql into a php object. The query includes references to the group_concat MySQL function.

This returns an object with a structure that includes group_concat as one of its keys (Please excuse / correct me if I am not using the correct terminology)

When I var_dump the $row variable, it looks like this:

> object(stdClass)#21 (2) { ["id"]=> string(4) "7583"
>   ["group_concat(resourceId)"]=> string(2) "25,26"}

I can reference the id by using: $row->id , but I can't reference the resourceId by using $row->group_concat(resourceId)

I get the following error:

> Call to undefined method stdClass::group_concat()

Please let me know how I can get hold of the data in that group_concat(resourceId) field?

Thank you.

Comment: You should always give aggregate columns an alias, see juergen_d's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an alias for your `group_concat` in your select statement. Something like

```
select group_concat(resourceId) as res_group
from your_table
```

Then you can reference that "column" with the alias name.